# How to run Selenium 2.0 RC -htmlSuite with WebDriver?

Tags: webdriver, htmlsuite

I tried Selenium 2.0 (documentation says it's using WebDriver) as so:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0a1.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" ...
```

but it seems that the WebDriver backend isn't used (especially since I haven't installed any Firefox plugin)? All Selenium 2.0 documentation uses Java interface, but it seems that using HTML suite uses the classic Selenium backend?

I've found no documentation on how to set up things for htmlSuite, but using the "headless" (HtmlUnit) version is totally OK (I don't need Firefox).

**Edit:** Selenium says `RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://...:4444/wd/hub` when starting up... Any idea of what to do and how?

**Edit 2:** Rewriting the test in Java using WebDriverBackedSelenium works. Thus the problems arise from htmlSuite not implemented using WebDriverBackedSelenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've uncovered in the code, Selenium RC and WebDriver are not yet merged. I may be wrong here, but I think the only way to use WebDriverBackedSelenium is directly in your Java test harness. If you're using a language other than Java to drive Selenium RC, you're SOL as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's my conclusion exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that WebDriverBackedSelenium is not yet supported, and continue to write my system/integration tests for GWT in Java instead of HTML.